# Adding integers with the eval function is returning an error. (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js

Please don't ask me not to use eval, this isn't going to be public anyways.

I've made a chatting website, and I have implemented a "!eval" command (admin only), whatever is after it is run. I can use "!eval '2'+'2'" (Strings added), but not "!eval 2+2." The error returned is [image].

I've console.logged the input to the eval, and it returned exactly what I wanted: "1+1." I've looked around for this, but it seems like no one else had this problem before. A solution (more like a debugging one) is that I tried "eval('1+1')" and returned the same error. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

(I forgot to add what I was expecting)

[image]

I was expecting this.

Comment: "*A solution (more like a debugging one) is that I tried "eval('1+1')" and returned the same error*" [it doesn't](https://jsbin.com/dokifed/edit?js,console). If you get an error from `eval('1+1')` then there must be other code involved. Please provide a [mcve] that accurately shows what are you running and how it produces an error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm 13, with no experience with stack overflow haha. Thanks, I'll try to look more into it

Answer (score 0):

VLAZ pointed out in the comments that it must be another piece of code, which he is correct. I was encrypting the messages so it can be sent securely to the client, and it only takes a string. I added

```
if (typeof(results) != 'string'){
      results = String(results)
}
```

and it seemed to work, Thanks!

Comment: I'm waiting 2 days so I can accept my own answer (or if VLAZ decides to make one, I'll mark his as a solution)